# Time is not getting saved from magento admin form?

Tags: magento-1.8, date, timezone

I have created a field in custom admin form with following code

```
$fieldset->addField('post_date', 'date', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('sprung_blog')->__('Date'),
        'name'  => 'post_date',
        'required'  => true,
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'format'  => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
    ));
```

But its only saving the date i have selected.How can i get the time too.

In my saveAction i have following too

```
$data = $this->_filterDates($data, array('post_date'));
```

I have tried by changing it to

```
$fieldset->addField('post_date', 'date', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('sprung_blog')->__('Date'),
        'name'  => 'post_date',
        'required'  => true,
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'time' => true,
        'format'  => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
    ));
```

Now i can see time in field.But in controller it comes as `[post_date] => 2014-07-24`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run `$productData = $this->_filterDates($productData, $dateFields);` for dates and `_filterDateTime` for datetime values on them. To make a mysql-readable format out of them, before saving

Comment: Already i have added it.But only its showing date that i selected.Time is saved as 00:00

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: You did all the normal stuff, like cleaning the cache, right? :-)

Comment: Yes..I can select time and its there on field.But when i print it in saveAction() it shows only date. Time value is not coming.

Comment: sorry, you have to use `_filterDateTime`, updated the answer